# Export Text with Colors

Tags: export, color

Is there a way of using `Export[]` method to take a text with colors (using `Style`) and then export to file, such that when I open that file the text shows with the correct color?

I'm trying to export a list of strings with some styles to be read in a text processor such as Microsoft Word.

Comment: For starters you need so specify a file type that supports colors.  `pdf` , `html` ? depends of what you are trying to do.

Comment: RTF format might be a good choice for opening in Word

Comment: Yeah, I think the same, but it is not woking, could you put some example, please.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge for me was concatenating styled strings. To concatenated the styled text for output, just put a space between them. With that the styles export successfully:

```
    Export["test.rtf", 
        Style["Arff", Red] Style["Meow", Blue]
    ]
```

That made the text is colored correctly when opened with Word on Windows.
You can also try:

```
    Export["test.html", 
      Style["Arff", Red] Style["Meow", Blue]
    ]
```

Which might work cross platform - this file loaded okay in the IE, but not Word.

Comment: Actually, your example it doesn't work too. I'm using Mathematica 10.1 on OS X 10.10

Comment: I am using 10.1, but on Windows. I will try using an HTML file as the export...

Comment: the syntax here cant be right.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
list = Style @@@ ColorData["Crayola", "ColorRules"];

Export["test.rtf", Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ #, "Output"] & /@ list]
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work too. Do you run it on OSX? I'm guessing that it could be a bug or something weird.

Comment: @d555, no I'm using Windows. Looks like you have a Mac specific bug...